# ApplicationPropertiesAccess cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, application-server, netweaver

I'm trying to implement an [Accessing Application Properties](https://help.sap.com/viewer/89439979a9c6495ea0ea249a6787d781/7.4.19/en-US/4ac346b53d142055e10000000a421937.html) functionality.

In SAP's code snippet there is a line:

```java
ApplicationPropertiesAccess appCfgProps = (ApplicationPropertiesAccess) ctx.lookup("ApplicationConfiguration");
```

The problem is that my NWDS can't resolve `ApplicationPropertiesAccess`, I get an error:

> ApplicationPropertiesAccess cannot be resolved to a type

SAP JVM version: 8.1.030

Why can't NWDS/Eclipse resolve `ApplicationPropertiesAccess`?

Comment: Have you added required references to your DC? Look at [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/05/25/how-to-add-reference-to-sap-provided-jars-in-pdk-web-dynpro-java-on-nwds-73/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a lack of the required ***DC***. Based on [SAP NetWeaver 7.20 (SP01)](https://help.sap.com/doc/javadocs_nwce_current/7.2.1/en-US/en/com.sap.en/com/sap/engine/services/configuration/appconfiguration/ApplicationPropertiesAccess.html) JavaDoc, in order to recognize `ApplicationProperties` and to be able to add:

```java
import com.sap.engine.services.configuration.appconfiguration.ApplicationPropertiesAccess;
```

we have to add ***tc/je/appconfiguration/api*** DC to the ***Dependencies → Required DCs*** via ***Component Properties***.